# Selenium get url address response from server

Tags: python, selenium

I try to get url address response from 'zumi' server with python selenium.

for example:
'https://www.zumi.pl/2421025,Marcin_Piatek_Pimar,Warszawa,firma.html#homePage'

when i type below in browser:

'https://www.zumi.pl/2421025,a,a,firma.html'

i get above response.

Now i try to get this response with python selenium:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.zumi.pl/2421025,a,a,firma.html'
browser.get(url)

current_url = browser.current_url
```

how to handle this to get proper response like:
'https://www.zumi.pl/2421025,Marcin_Piatek_Pimar,Warszawa,firma.html#homePage'

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution with help of:

https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.zumi.pl/Drukarnie+Bartk%C3%B3w,namapie.html'
browser.get(url)

# get browser session parameters
executor_url = browser.command_executor._url
session_id = browser.session_id

# create remote second browser with session data from first one
browser_session = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url, desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
browser_session.session_id = session_id

# url for response
url2 = 'https://www.zumi.pl/3108553,a,a,firma.html'

# get response from url2
browser_session.get(url2)
proper_url = browser_session.current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

> That should resolve your problems without creating the second browser session:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import traceback

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")


url = 'https://www.zumi.pl/2421025,a,a,firma.html'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

try:

    button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.cmp-closebutton_hasBorder >svg > path')
    button[0].click()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

Where **cmp-closebutton_hasBorder** is model header close span tag class

I tested on Ubuntu-18.04 and chrome-browser-74.0